# SPA usando requirejs y jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

Buenas comunidad, estoy tratando de migrar un proyecto usando la librería require.js para realizar módulos asíncronos, pero me he encontrados con problemas que no se como resolver. Tratando de utilizar variables para guardar templates como por ejemplo

**Index_Ctrl.js**

```
define({

    titulo: "Probando AMD con Require.js y Jquery",
    cuerpo: "Esto es una muestra de como debe funcionar\n\
             require js y jquery, su configuracion, entre otras cosas\n\
             un estilo MVC."

});
```

**Index_tpl.js**

```
define(['IndexCtrl'], function (IndexCtrl){


var index_page = {

    template: function (){

        var titulo, cuerpo;

        titulo = IndexCtrl.titulo;
        cuerpo = IndexCtrl.cuerpo;

        var html = '<h1>'+ titulo +'</h1>'+
                   '<p>' + cuerpo + '</p>'+
                   '<button id="btn_menu">Menu</button>';

        $('#contenedor').append(html);
    }

};

return {
    template: index_page.template
};

});
```

index.html

```
<html>

<head>

    <title>AMD</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>

<body>

    <div id="contenedor">

    </div>

    <script data-main="js/app/main" src="js/libs/require.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

main.js

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'js',

    paths : {
      jquery : ['libs/jquery-1.12.0.min',
               'libs/jquery-2.2.0.min'],
  IndexTpl: 'app/Index_Tpl',
  IndexCtrl: 'app/Index_Ctrl',
  MenuTpl: 'app/Menu_Tpl',
  MenuCtrl: 'app/Menu_Ctrl'
},

shim: {
    IndexTpl: ['jquery'],
    MenuTpl: ['jquery']
}


});

define(['IndexTpl', 'MenuTpl'], function (index, menu){


index.template();

});
```

Quisiera que al hacer click en un boton un modulo para usar otro template que son los siguientes

Menu_Tpl.js

```
define(['MenuCtrl'], function (MenuCtrl){

    var menu_page = {

        template_m: function (){

            var titulo, cuerpo;

            titulo = MenuCtrl.titulo;
            cuerpo = MenuCtrl.cuerpo;

            var html = '<h1>'+ titulo +'</h1>'+
                       '<p>' + cuerpo + '</p>'+
                       '<button id="btn_index">Index</button>';

            $('#contenedor').append(html);
        }

    };

    return {
        template_m: menu_page.template_m
    };

});
```

Menu_Ctrl.js

```
define({

    titulo: "Probando AMD con Require.js y Jquery",
    cuerpo: "Este es el menu de prueba."

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que hacer varios cambios para que te funcione, te los detallo a continuación

### Archivo main.js

Sustituir el último `define` por un `require` porque es la forma de obtener las dependencias

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'js',

    paths : {
    jquery : ['libs/jquery-1.12.0.min',
            'libs/jquery-2.2.0.min'],
    IndexTpl: 'app/Index_Tpl',
    IndexCtrl: 'app/Index_Ctrl',
    MenuTpl: 'app/Menu_Tpl',
    MenuCtrl: 'app/Menu_Ctrl'
    },

    shim: {
        IndexTpl: ['jquery'],
        MenuTpl: ['jquery']
    }

});

require(['IndexTpl'], function (index){

    index.template();

});
```

### Archivo Index_Tpl.js

Capturar el `click` del botón y dentro usar `require` para obtener la referencia a la plantilla `index` y ejecutar la plantilla
También deberías cambiar la forma de identificar el botón cambiando el atributo `id`por un atributo `data`

```
define(['IndexCtrl'], function (IndexCtrl){      

    var index_page = {

        template: function (){

            var titulo, cuerpo;

            titulo = IndexCtrl.titulo;
            cuerpo = IndexCtrl.cuerpo;

            var html = '<h1>'+ titulo +'</h1>'+
                    '<p>' + cuerpo + '</p>'+
                    '<button data-action="btn_menu">Ir al Menu</button>';

            $('#contenedor').html(html);

            $('button[data-action="btn_menu"]').on('click', function (){        
                require(['MenuTpl'], function(menu){ 
                    menu.template();
                });                            
            }); 

        }        
    };   

    return {
        template: index_page.template
    };

});
```

### Archivo Menu_Tpl.js

Haríamos los mismos cambios que en `Index_tpl.js`

```
define(['MenuCtrl'], function (MenuCtrl){

    var menu_page = {

        template: function (){

            var titulo, cuerpo;

            titulo = MenuCtrl.titulo;
            cuerpo = MenuCtrl.cuerpo;

            var html = '<h1>'+ titulo +'</h1>'+
                    '<p>' + cuerpo + '</p>'+
                    '<button data-action="btn_index">Ir al index</button>';

            $('#contenedor').html(html);

            $('button[data-action="btn_index"]').on('click', function (){        
                require(['IndexTpl'], function(index) {
                    index.template();  
                });                            
            }); 
        }

    };

    return {
        template: menu_page.template
    };

});
```

**En código completo está colgado en [GitHub](https://github.com/rsciriano/SO-SPA-requirejs)**

### Recomendaciones

- Algo que tenemos que tener muy presente cuando nos enfrentamos a un problema es que **no debemos reinvertar la rueda** y creo que es lo que podrías estar haciendo tu *(disculpa por ser tan directo, no pretendo ofenderte, es algo que también me digo a mi mismo)*
- Te recomiendo que uses uno de los numerosos frameworks **SPA** que existen,  [AngularJs](https://angularjs.org/), [Aurelia](http://aurelia.io/), ... proporcionan numerosas ventajas (sistema de plantillas, binding, enrutado, inyección de dependencias, ...
- Personalmente elegí `AngularJs` porque está muy extendido en la comunidad, es muy potente y te incitaba a tener tu código ordenado con la gestión de módulos, inyección de dependencias.
- En cuanto a la carga asíncrona de elementos (una de las funciones de `requirejs`) tiene que estar muy justificada (por ejemplo para aplicaciones muy muy grandes) porque, entre otras cosas, añade mucha complejidad.

Comment: Gracias, ya logre hacer algo pero siempre me pasa lo mismo, no creo que pueda, pasar el link para que descargues y pruebes el index y ver que dices
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4-mGtqp0ZxqeWx4Qm14Y1YtOFE/view

Comment: Alli esta el archivo, si puedes dscargarlo y descomprimirlo, y luego abrs el index y pruebas los botones, y entenderas, mejor lo que digo yo

Comment: Hola @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales, me he descardado tu código y he conseguido que funcione y he reescrito mi respuesta. Por cierto, ¿que te motivado a querer hacerlo con `requirejs` y no usar una librería `SPA` como `angularjs`?

Comment: he estado pensando en hacerlo con algun framework MVC o MVVM, y de todos pues el que tiene según he visto, tengo descargados unos tutoriales pero como ando terminando mi libro para podr graduarme entonces me queda un poco de para arriba ya sabras tu como se pon todo, mi aplicacion quiero migrarla a angular con ionic framework, supongo que la conoces, pero tengo unas dudas, pues no es facil asimilar angular de una vez he estado practicando poco, no se si me puedas ayudar a despejar unas dudas, gracias por la explicacion muy buena

Comment: Hola @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales un buen recurso para empezar con `Angular` es libro ["Desarrollo web ágil con Angular.js"](https://carlosazaustre.es/blog/ebook-angular/) de [Carlos Azaustre](http://twitter.com/carlosazaustre). En su web también tienes  [este](https://goo.gl/6m76zk) tutorial que tiene buena pinta. Ionic me parece buena opción, pero antes deberías aprender Angular (por lo menos lo básico). Por cierto, si por lo que parece te ha sido útil mi respuesta, marcarla como aceptada. Saludos

Comment: Ya disculpa se me habia pasado lo de marcarla, gracias por la ayuda