# require con Babel

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babel

Estoy tratando de transpilar algunos .js usando Babel. Uso jquery por tanto la primera linea del archivo origen es:

```
import { $, jQuery } from 'jquery';
```

El procedimiento de compilación es exitoso, pero en el archivo generado , la primera linea es:

```
require("core-js/modules/web.dom.iterable");
```

La cual al ser invocada en el navegador dispara el error:

```
xxx.js:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

Es decir el archivo generado por Babel usa la instrucción require la cual es a su vez una instrucción de ES6 y no es soporta por el navegador. Alguna idea?

Answer (score 2):

para lograr lo que te propones, te recomiendo que uses RequireJS.

Como indica en su página web [RequireJS](https://requirejs.org/), esta utilidad te permitirá realizar la carga de módulos y archivos en el navegador de la misma forma que lo haces con Node.

Puedes consultar la [documentación de RequireJS](https://requirejs.org/docs/start.html)

Una forma en cómo puedes usarlo sería: (luego de descargar el archivo require.js)

Supongamos que tu archivo transpilado es `main.js` y lo almacenas en la carpeta `scripts` de tu deployment, entonces en la sección `<head>` de tu archivo `html` colocas el siguiente `tag`:

```
<script data-main="scripts/main" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
```

Así de simple ya puedes cargar módulos o archivos usando `require()`.

Tomando en cuenta que deseas usar JQuery, debes hacer algunos pasos adicionales de configuración. Dichos pasos van a depender de cómo estés realizando tu implementación.

Puedes leer más al respecto en [How to use RequireJS with JQuery](https://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html)

Es la documentación oficial, está en inglés.

Esta respuesta de SO en español puede darte una orientación de la configuración:
[SPA usando requirejs y jquery](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/3766/spa-usando-requirejs-y-jquery)

También puedes consultar este post: [¿Qué es y cómo funciona RequireJS?](http://7sabores.com/blog/como-funciona-requirejs) para una introducción básica en español.